# How do i solve the internal server error in azure functions using an HTTP trigger

Tags: python, azure

I'm trying to make an azure function that is triggered via an HTTP connection and this function triggers another function (MyFunction1). The reason for this is to use Data Factory to trigger the function. However, when I try to use the test run in the azure function app, I get the message "500 internal server error". The code and my input can be found below:

**init**.py :

```
from dir1.dir2.keyvault import get_secret

import argparse
import pathlib
import logging

FILE_DIR = pathlib.Path(__file__).parent.resolve()

log = logging.getLogger(__name__)

import azure.functions as func

def main(req: func.HttpRequest) -> func.HttpResponse:
    logging.info('Python HTTP trigger function processed a request.')
    MyFunction1()
    return func.HttpResponse(f"Hello there, This HTTP triggered function executed successfully.")
```

[image: Input]

Comment: Where is the declaration of MyFunction1??

Comment: Have you checked the logs where the exact problem is..?